# Mostrar os valores de Parametros de multi-valores Report Viewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Estou com uma duvida, como consigo exibir todos os valores gravados em um Parametro de MultiValores no Report Viewer (C#), consigo exibir um valor de uma posição especifica (Parameters!Teste.Value(0)), porém queria mostrar todos os valores,sendo um em cada linha.

Comment: Qual código você tem até o momento?

Comment: Eu preciso lista os valores que estão dentro do parâmetro, até agora eu consigo mostrar, apenas um valor dentro do parâmetro, especificando a posição n (Parameters!Teste.Value(n)), eu queria listar ele automaticamente, assim como fazemos com os parâmetros do dataset